# How to use relative references in active cell formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am inserting a new table row button. It needs to add rows to two seperate tables. The formula in the second row needs to reference the row that was inserted in the other table.

So I have tried the following for the second table row insert:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("Table2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND('Sheet2'!R[-452]C[10]>=R1C4,'Sheet2'!R[-452]C[10]<=R1C5),'Sheet2'!R[-452]C[-1],"""")"
    Range("C481").Select
End Sub
```

So my formula is meant to add a row to table2 row 480, that has the formula referring to the new row added in sheet2 table1, which would be row 13 (currently).

Is there a way to do this?
Currently I manually copy and paste the following formula in the cells:

```
=IF(AND('Sheet2'!$M13>=$D$1,'Sheet2'!$M13<=$E$1),'Sheet2'!B13,"")
```

Comment: yeah, it is possible, if the number of rows in both tables is different that means the formula in table 2 will not be consistent across the entire column, is that fine? which column of table 2 are you inserting the formula?

Comment: So all the  new cells in table2 would require the formula, there are the same amount of columns in both. It would be the last cell reference ("B13") that should change, e.g. in table 2 column A the formula would be for "A13", then table2 column N it would be the same formula but "N13"?

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure about the position of your tables in the sheet and since in the formula you are using absolute addresses so I was able to guess which columns you were using to reference in the formula. As an example, this code will create a formula in the first column and last row of Table2 referencing the first column and last row of Table1 after it creates a new row in Table1 and Table2. You can adjust the formula as you want. There is only one caveat here that Excel will duplicate the formulas when you run the code for the first time since there is no formula in an empty column, if you delete the formula in other rows, it won't do that again when you run it for the second time.

```
Sub CreateFormula()
    Dim indx1 As Integer 'index of the row added to table1
    Dim indx2 As Integer 'index of the row added to table2

    Dim loRow1 As ListRow 'table row that will be added in table1
    Dim loRow2 As ListRow 'table row that will be added in table2

    Dim tbl1 As ListObject
    Dim tbl22 As ListObject

    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range

    'define tables first
    Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1") 'Activesheet can be thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

    'Insert new rows
    Set loRow1 = tbl1.ListRows.Add
    Set loRow2 = tbl2.ListRows.Add

    'get the index of the newly added rows
    indx1 = loRow1.Index
    indx2 = loRow2.Index

    'indert the formula
    Set cell1 = tbl1.DataBodyRange(indx1, 1) 'we will reference this in the formula
    Set cell2 = tbl2.DataBodyRange(indx2, 1) 'we will put the formula in this cell

    cell2.Formula = "=if(" & cell1.Address & ">0," & "1,0)"


End Sub
```